# scrapyd: curl error `unknown or corrupt egg`

Tags: python-2.7, scrapyd

I'am trying to update version of my spider, i wrote:

`curl http://localhost:6800/addversion.json -d project=comicvn -d spider=comicvn2 -d version= 141667324 -d egg=14116674324.egg`

It made error : `{"status"": error,"message": "ValuesError: Unkow or corrupt egg"`

What's egg paramerter ? and what should I set values for it ? Thank so much !

I created '14116674324.egg' by ussing command `bdist_egg`. After that, it made a `14116674324.egg` file in path :`C:\Python27\Scripts\eggs\comicvn2` , so i copy this file to root folder of my project like `C:\Python27\Scripts\comicvn2`.

Comment: to deploy to scrapyd just open a terminal, cd to your project root and type `scrapy deploy`

Comment: thanks to comment, but I did it, now, i want to update version of spider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see `scrapy.cfg` format at [scrapy deploy](http://scrapyd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/deploy.html) doc page. change version entry to update the spider version

```
[deploy]
url = http://scrapyd.mydomain.com
username = john
password = secret
project = project1
version = 123
```

Answer (score 2):

curl http://localhost:6800/addversion.json -d project=comicvn -d spider=comicvn2 -d version= 141667324 -d egg=@14116674324.egg

you must be add '@'